# Where to put SVN repository directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, svn

I am setting up a new SVN server on Ubuntu Linux. Where is a good place (best practice) to put the repositories? Should I create a new user? The server will be accessed via http:// so no need to create user accounts etc (as was the case for svn://).

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Probably better to ask this on server fault...

Comment: That makes sense. I'll try to move it later.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I like putting things under `/srv`, as it seems to match the definition in the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM).

Comment: OK I'll go with the majority decision. Actually all of the suggestions below makes sense, I initially put under /var/svn as well because its next to my htdocs, but I guess the standard is there for a reason...

Answer (score 4):

The new location for service data according to the FHS is [`/srv`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM), so under there would probably be best.

Answer (score 3):

I've always used `/var/svn` or `/var/lib/svn`.  While it doesn't quite line up with [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM), it matches closer to what the other apps actually do (On RHEL5, Apache uses `/var/www`; PostgreSQL uses `/var/lib/pgsql`).  As suggested, `/srv/svn` looks like another good spot.  And you get to say "Look, I'm following [the standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM)!"

Using either `/usr/svn` or `/usr/local/svn` would probably be considered *bad form*, and all your Linux friends will laugh at you behind your back :-)

Comment: `/var/www` is an old cruftiness that the devs really, really wish they could fix.

Answer (score 1):

I host my SVN via the apache module, so I usually put it under my apache user, at the same level as my htdocs, and setup a specific authentication just for SVN users. Not under htdocs, but same level.

If you have a lot of projects, dedicate another volume to SVN since it will grow.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'm kind of old school but I like to put things (apache,tomcat,...etc)  in /usr/local. So I will usually create repositories in /usr/local/svn and have the Apache module reference that path in the httpd.conf

Comment: That is old school.  For a long time, there's been something of a Linux policy that files under /usr are more or less static.  I put my repository under /var before I moved to Mercurial.

Answer (score -4):

```
/home/username/Dropbox
```

this way you backup the svn and can access it on a windows machine as well.