# SVN+Apache: Where to store repositories

Tags: apache, svn

I have been keeping all my Subversion repositories on my local computer for a while, but now I decided to move them to my web hosting server. It's an apache server and the hosting company has set up svn. My question is, where should I store my svn repositories. I originally stored them in the `public_html/` directory, but (I'm certainly no security expert) I think only publicly available web content should be stored there. On the other hand, if I try storing the repositories in `~/var/svn/` then my subversion client (Eclipse) says "no element found". How do other people store their repositories with regards to Apache? Thank you.

Comment: This may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480078/where-to-put-svn-repository-directory-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

You can select **any** *physical* location for your repositories collection, because *logical* path is defined inside Apache (Location container + SVNPath|SVNParentPath) later. You have only

- select big partition (repository may require a lot of space)
- don't forget chown|chmod repo dirs, in order to give Apache process the ability to handle files of repository

/var (/var/repos/) is good candidate for repo-root

Comment: however, `/var` is the conventional root for things like data/log/repo files

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would store data in an appropriate subdirectory of `/var` (not `~/var`), that is if you have access to it. E.g. `/var/svn`

Comment: It's a shared server from my webhosting service, so I don't (think I) have access to anything outside of my home directory. But even if I did, it looks like Apache will only serve files out of ~/public_html, so I still can't figure out how I'd get my Subversion client to connect to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

We haven't adopted SVN for our web source yet, but have been using CVS.  Our solution was to simply prevent Apache from serving the CVS store using `IndexIgnore`

```
IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t
```

You may be able to do something similar, using something based upon `.svn`.

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult if you are using a shared web hosting, because you need to have an access to root, to create svn-group and creating the structure of the repository. You also need to install some module on Apache like dav_svn. You will need to create a VirtualHost (sites-available) in order to serve your repos over a  specific DNS.

There is a lot of tutorial on the inter-webs -> http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-subversion-svn-with-apache2-and-dav/ (for ubuntu)

Me, I rent a Virtual Private Server to host my SVN.